# Формирование ссылок через route с https laravel

Tags: php, laravel, https, route

На сайте есть ссылки которые задаются через route например:

```
{{route('admin',['method'=>'index','lang'=>$lang])}}
```

В результате получаю ссылку `http://` вопрос:
Как сделать чтобы ссылки формировались `https` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `route` разве не создает относительный путь по умолчанию? Если вы находитесь на странице с `https` - у вас такой же `url` и будет создан.

Как альтурнативу попробуйте явно указать в `AppServiceProvider` в методе `boot`:

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Если версия ниже 5.4:

```
URL::forceSchema('https');
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php задайте свойство $proxies. Без установленного этого свойства метод isSecure() объекта \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request будет всегда выдавать false и, соответственно, в урлах будет везде http.  В данном случае, чтобы все заработало, можете просто задать такое значение:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Детальнее в документации https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies